# QGIS variables as part of the interface

Tags: qgis, user-interface, qgis-variable

I've recently learned about how to use variables in QGIS. They are, however not that easily accessible as they are for example in Graphical Modeller, where they are part of the interface. Is it possible to have "some" of user-defined variables to be always accessible either as a Panel or a Toolbar? Meaning, it would not need to open additional window to change the variable, I can just click and change it directly. If this is not understandable, I can try to visualise it.